# Emit data POSTED to nodejs server to client

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have the following nodejs server code

```
    http = require('http');
    fs = require('fs');
    url = require('url');
    server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {

        console.dir(req.param);

        if (req.method == 'POST') {
            console.log("POST");
// I WANT TO EMIT THIS DATA TO CLIENT
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("GET");
        }

    });

//THIS IS A WORKING EXAMPLE WHICH I FOUND ONLINE TIED TOGETHER

    io = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io').listen(server);

    io.sockets.on( 'connection', function ( socket ) {
      console.log("runing time");
      sendTimeMessage(socket);
    });


    function sendTimeMessage(socket){
      console.log("in time");
      var now= new Date().getTime();
      socket.emit('notification', {'message': now});
      setTimeout(function() {
        socket.emit('notification', {'message': "after 5s"});
      },5000);
    }

    port = 8000;
    host = '127.0.0.1';
    server.listen(port, host);
    console.log('Listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
```

CLIENT SIDE

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>

        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

        socket.on('notification', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id='messages'></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please excuse this example. What I wanted to achieve is, when a post happens to my nodejs server , I want to emit it to the frontend. I am a fresh begineer on nodejs and socket, but I am aware of how javascript works.

Is there a way I can put the socketio emit in the POST?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending data to the server that uses sockets, send it over the socket instead of doing it through a post request. Or, if you must use post, you can send it back to the client via res.send('data goes here');

If neither of these options work for you, then perhaps you could set up some sort of in-between. For instance, log the data from the post request to a database and have a script that polls the database for changes and then pushes them through the socket. This is hacky and definitely not the recommended way of doing it.

EDIT: Another way to do this might be to create a global variable (yuck), that is a list of sockets with some sort of ID as the key. Then send that ID with your post request, and grab the socket from your global variable and send the data from there. For instance:

```
var sockets = {};
var server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        // You will need to pass the socket ID from the client
        sockets[request.data.id].emit('Some data');
    }
});

var io = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function ( socket ) {
  sockets[socket.id] = socket;
});
```

**This is untested and not guaranteed to be free of security flaws**